# Joint.js Drag and Drop Element between two papers

Tags: javascript, svg, drag-and-drop, jointjs

I am implementing drag and drop between two papers .But I am stuck with the syncing of offset of dragged element with cursor position as I have two papers in my html body.I have very minute experience with css which may be causing problem of positioning of elements.

Use Case:-

User clicks on element from paper 2 and starts dragging and go to paper 1.
On Pointer up a clone of that element is added to paper 1 on the position of cursor in paper 1.

My strategy to handle this is :-

When the user clicks mousedown

1.Dynamically create a div

2.Create a third paper, say call it  "flypaper" in the new div
Make a copy of the element that you want to clone, and add it to "flypaper"

3.Create a mousemove listener that  will move the div containing "flypaper" with the mouse

4.Add a mouseup event that will add a clone of the element to the "paper2" when the user releases the button.

5.Clean up the "flypaper" div and events.

```
<body>
<div id="paper" class="paper" style="border-style: solid;border-width: 5px;width:600px"></div>
<div id="paper2" class="paper" style="border-style: solid;border-width: 5px;width:600px;display:inline-block" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<script>
    var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;
    var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
        el: $('#paper'),
        width: 600,
        height: 200,
        model: graph,
        gridSize: 1

    });
    var rect = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
        position: { x: 100, y: 30 },
        size: { width: 100, height: 30 },
        attrs: { rect: { fill: 'blue' }, text: { text: 'my box', fill: 'white' } }
    });
    graph.addCells([rect]);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    var graph2 = new joint.dia.Graph;
    var paper2 = new joint.dia.Paper({
        el: $('#paper2'),
        width: 600,
        height: 200,
        model: graph2,
        gridSize: 1
    });
    paper2.on('cell:pointerup',function (cellView, evt, x, y) {
        var rect4 = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
            position: { x: 10, y: 50 },
            size: { width: 100, height: 30 },
            attrs: { rect: { fill: 'blue' }, text: { text: 'my box', fill: 'white' } }
        });

        graph.addCells([rect4]);
    });
    paper2.on('cell:pointerdown',function (cellView, evt, x, y) {
        $('body').append('<div id="flyPaper" class="box" style="position: fixed;z-index: 100;display:block;opacity:.7;"></div>');
        var graph3 = new joint.dia.Graph;
        var paper3 = new joint.dia.Paper({
            el: $('#flyPaper'),
            width: 600,
            height: 200,
            model: graph3,
            gridSize: 1
        });
        var rect3 = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
            position: { x: 10, y: 50 },
            size: { width: 100, height: 30 },
            attrs: { rect: { fill: 'blue' }, text: { text: 'my box', fill: 'white' } }
        });

        graph3.addCells([rect3]);
        $('body').mousemove(function(e){
            var mouseX   =  e.pageX; //get mouse move position
            var mouseY   =  e.pageY;
            $( "div.box" ).offset({ top: mouseY, left: mouseX });
            // $('div.box',this).css({'top': boxPositionY,'left': boxPositionX})
        });

    });

    var rect2 = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
        position: { x: 10, y: 50 },
        size: { width: 100, height: 30 },
        attrs: { rect: { fill: 'blue' }, text: { text: 'my box', fill: 'white' } }
    });
    graph2.addCells([rect2]);
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 25):

I had the same problem (and have clients who won't pay for [rappid](http://jointjs.com/rappid/tour) which adds this feature to [jointjs](http://jointjs.com/)). So here's a snippet that may help others (see below).

The steps are th same as you pointed out: 
1.Dynamically create a div
2.Create a third paper, say call it "flypaper" in the new div Make a copy of the element that you want to clone, and add it to "flypaper"
3.Create a mousemove listener that will move the div containing "flypaper" with the mouse
4.Add a mouseup event that will add a clone of the element to the "paper2" when the user releases the button.
5.Clean up the "flypaper" div and events.

The solution to your problem was to use `cellView.model.clone()` to add the right element and then some computation with `$.offset`, `$.width()` & `$.height()` to get the right flyingpaper postion and to check if the drop event occured on the target paper.

[View on codepen](https://codepen.io/fxaeberard/pen/reGvjm)

```
<body>
<div id="paper" class="paper" style="border-style: solid;border-width: 5px;width:600px"></div>
<div id="paper2" class="paper" style="border-style: solid;border-width: 5px;width:600px;display:inline-block"></div>
<script>
    // Canvas where sape are dropped
    var graph = new joint.dia.Graph,
      paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
        el: $('#paper'),
        model: graph
      });

    // Canvas from which you take shapes
    var stencilGraph = new joint.dia.Graph,
      stencilPaper = new joint.dia.Paper({
        el: $('#stencil'),
        height: 60,
        model: stencilGraph,
        interactive: false
      });

    var r1 = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
      position: {
        x: 10,
        y: 10
      },
      size: {
        width: 100,
        height: 40
      },
      attrs: {
        text: {
          text: 'Rect1'
        }
      }
    });
    var r2 = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
      position: {
        x: 120,
        y: 10
      },
      size: {
        width: 100,
        height: 40
      },
      attrs: {
        text: {
          text: 'Rect2'
        }
      }
    });
    stencilGraph.addCells([r1, r2]);

    stencilPaper.on('cell:pointerdown', function(cellView, e, x, y) {
      $('body').append('<div id="flyPaper" style="position:fixed;z-index:100;opacity:.7;pointer-event:none;"></div>');
      var flyGraph = new joint.dia.Graph,
        flyPaper = new joint.dia.Paper({
          el: $('#flyPaper'),
          model: flyGraph,
          interactive: false
        }),
        flyShape = cellView.model.clone(),
        pos = cellView.model.position(),
        offset = {
          x: x - pos.x,
          y: y - pos.y
        };

      flyShape.position(0, 0);
      flyGraph.addCell(flyShape);
      $("#flyPaper").offset({
        left: e.pageX - offset.x,
        top: e.pageY - offset.y
      });
      $('body').on('mousemove.fly', function(e) {
        $("#flyPaper").offset({
          left: e.pageX - offset.x,
          top: e.pageY - offset.y
        });
      });
      $('body').on('mouseup.fly', function(e) {
        var x = e.pageX,
          y = e.pageY,
          target = paper.$el.offset();

        // Dropped over paper ?
        if (x > target.left && x < target.left + paper.$el.width() && y > target.top && y < target.top + paper.$el.height()) {
          var s = flyShape.clone();
          s.position(x - target.left - offset.x, y - target.top - offset.y);
          graph.addCell(s);
        }
        $('body').off('mousemove.fly').off('mouseup.fly');
        flyShape.remove();
        $('#flyPaper').remove();
      });
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: If drag and drop has to work for links, what changes needs to be made ?

Comment: Hi @François-XavierAeberhard. I am trying your code,  but what if i need to change the name of process after dragging, if i drag to rectangles i want ti give two different names for two rectangles

Comment: @Keerthi Reddy Yeruva, I have the same requirement. Did you find the solution? Thanks!

Comment: @konekoya Can you elaborate, not sure i understand the question

Comment: Thanks for replying @François-XavierAeberhard! Your snippet works out pretty well for me. But I have a requirement which was mentioned in the above comments by Keerthi: what if i need to change the name of process after dragging? Maybe something like a prompt or a text editor?

Comment: This is for double click event. Similarly there is drop event paper.on('cell:pointerdblclick', (cellView, e, x, y) => { 
                                            
graph.getCell(cellView.model.id).attributes.attrs['.label'].text = "changedname"; });

Comment: I noticed that the flyPaper variable is unused. Is there some sort of quirk that makes it still necessary?